# I have a project for school and I'm almost done with it but for some reason something isn't working. Also keep in mind that I'm using ES5

Tags: javascript, constructor, scope, javascript-objects

<

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = console.log(coin.test = 10)">run 'coin.test = 10'</button>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = console.log(coin.total)">run 'coin.total'</button>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('heads').innerHTML = console.log(coin.heads)">run 'coin.heads'</button>
 
<p id="test"></p>
<p id="total"></p>

<p id="heads"></p>



<script>
function appendItem(list, item) {
  list.push(item);
}

function randomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}



var list = ["last","hi"];






    function template(l, o){
  
  var obj = this;
  
  this.list = l;
  
  this.options = o;
  
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'test', { 
    set: function(numberOfTests) {
      for(var i = 0; i < numberOfTests; i++){
        appendItem(obj.list, obj.options[randomNumber(0, this.options.length - 1)]);
      }
      //console.log(obj.list);
      return obj.list;
      
    }
  });
  

  for(var i = 0; i < obj.options.length; i++){
      console.log(i);
      Object.defineProperty(obj, obj.options[i], {
        value: obj.options[i] + ":  " + (obj.list.filter(function(option){return option == obj.options[i];}))
          
    
      });
  
      
    }
  
  Object.defineProperty(obj, 'total', { 
    get: function() {
      var totalList = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < obj.options.length; i++){
        appendItem(totalList, obj.options[i] + ":  " + (obj.list.filter(function(option){return option == obj.options[i]}).length));
      }
      return totalList;
    }
  });
  
}





var coin = new template([], ["heads", "tails"]);
//var dice = new template([], ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]);


coin.test = 10; //returns an array of "heads" and "tails"
//console.log(coin.total);
//console.log(coin.heads);


    






</script>
```

> 

the "coin.heads" is what I am having an issue with. instead of logging the number of occurrences of heads( e.g.:  "heads: 4"), it logs "heads: " and I think its a problem of scope but when I added the variable 'obj'(local to the template function, also this is what my code is now originally it would return undefined or an error but I added and used the 'obj' and now it logs "heads: "), it still doesn't work. I've tried a bunch of things and none of them worked

Comment: It would help if you explain what you want to achieve. Most of that code seems unnecessary. Also, `appendItem` is not defined.

Comment: `appendItem` it missing in your code - I tried turning it into an SO snippet (try it, its the `<>` icon in the question editor) and it meant I couldn't test it. Please try to get all your code in the snippet. Also, this ia convoluted way to make a class - I don't even understand why your assign `this` to `obj` - it makes thing so much more confusing. Or why your variables are named `l` and `o`, just name them `list` and `options`. Makes everything clearer.

Comment: I added 'obj' because I was getting errors in some of the places where I used 'this'.  also the syntax is a little bit different because im using code.org which changed some of the functions

Comment: Hey don't worry, those were just tips. You don't have to edit that now. If you can get your code to run in an SO snippet - which should be possible if you add `appendItem` to the code here, or a mock method that generates the same output, then we can see. Its really hard to know why your code doesnt print anything since we have no idea what the contents are we need to look at.

Comment: @somethinghere alright i did it